# Como unir dos consultas mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Los 2 ultimos meses serian registros de salida los primeros 5 son de entrada
pero no puedo hacer que me aparezcan en cada columna y si no tiene valor ese mes que aparezca cero

```
select entrada, salida, mes 
FROM(
    select count(IdTipoRegistro) as entrada, count(IdTipoRegistro) as salida, Date_format(FechaRegistro,"%m") as mes from eventos where IdTipoRegistro=1 and Date_format(FechaRegistro,"%Y")=2021 group by Date_format(FechaRegistro,"%y-%m")
    union all
    select count(IdTipoRegistro) as entrada, count(IdTipoRegistro) as salida, Date_format(FechaRegistro,"%m") as mes from eventos where IdTipoRegistro=2 and Date_format(FechaRegistro,"%Y")=2021 group by Date_format(FechaRegistro,"%y-%m")
)e
group by mes
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

algo asi deberia quedar la parte amarilla deberia ser cero

Comment: ¿Que versión de MySql estás utilizando?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si hay meses que no existen en esas tablas, sql no los va a crear de la nada, necesitas tener una tabla calendario con todos los meses para joinearla y que aparezcan los que faltan....

Comment: version: 10.5.12-MariaDB

Comment: Agrega la etiqueta de MariaDB con la versión y quita la de MySql, ya que la respuesta puede varias según el motor de base de datos utilizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu query está casi bien, aunque en una de las subqueries de la `UNION` deberías haber contado solo las entradas y en la otra las salidas. La próxima vez comparte la estructura de tu tabla, un conjunto mínimo de datos de pruebas y el resultado esperado a partir de los datos de prueba.

Asumí `IdTipoRegistro = 1` como entrada y `IdTipoRegistro = 2` como salida, si están al revés los tendrás que modificar en mi query.

Utilicé una tabla de secuencias (`Sequence Storage Engine`) para generar los números de los meses (de 1 a 12; otra opción podría haber sido una `query recursiva`) y luego hice un `LEFT JOIN` con la subquery que hace el `UNION`. En dicha subquery utilizo dos subqueries, en la primera por cada entrada (`IdTipoRegistro = 1`) pongo un 1 y cero en las salidas; en la segunda subquery al revés. Luego agrupo por el número del mes generado y sumo las entradas y salidas por separado.

Para **MariaDB**:

```
SELECT mes.seq AS mes, sum(coalesce(entrada, 0)) AS entradas, sum(coalesce(salida, 0)) AS salidas

FROM seq_1_to_12 mes

LEFT JOIN (SELECT FechaRegistro, 1 AS entrada, 0 AS salida
           FROM eventos
           WHERE IdTipoRegistro = 1 AND Date_format(FechaRegistro, "%Y") = 2021 

           UNION ALL

           SELECT FechaRegistro, 0, 1
           FROM eventos
           WHERE IdTipoRegistro = 2 AND Date_format(FechaRegistro, "%Y") = 2021) AS sq ON mes.seq = Date_format(sq.FechaRegistro, "%m")

GROUP BY  mes.seq;
```

Otra opción en lugar de utilizar dos subqueries con `UNION`, es utilizar una sola subquery y dos sentencias `CASE` (una para las entradas y otra para las salidas):

```
SELECT mes.seq AS mes, count(entrada) AS entradas, count(salida) AS salidas

FROM seq_1_to_12 mes

LEFT JOIN (SELECT FechaRegistro, 
                  CASE WHEN IdTipoRegistro = 1 THEN 1 END AS entrada,
                  CASE WHEN IdTipoRegistro = 2 THEN 1 END AS salida
           FROM eventos
           WHERE year(FechaRegistro) = 2021) AS sq ON mes.seq = month(sq.FechaRegistro)

GROUP BY  mes.seq;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias 
Exactamente eso era lo que necesitaba 
agradecido eternamente

Comment: De nada @Cristian!!! Me alegro que te hayan sido util mis queries.

Answer (score -1):

ademas del union puede usar un inner join contra la misma tabla diferente alias despues pues pones los filtros clientes t1 , clientes t2 where t1.id=t2=id

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace? Podrías poner el código para ilustrar la respuesta.

Comment: un union pone una tabla luego de otra.. un join, pone una al costado de la otra.. como seria con un inner join en este caso?